# multi row update in update trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

how can i change this code to work with multi row update.@id is int and order_id is primary key, but i want to check every row that has status_b='bagged'

```
select @id=inserted.order_id from inserted;
 if update(status_b)
  begin
  if (select status_b from inserted)='bagged'
     begin
       if (select o.id 
                 from [order] o 
                 left join [print] p on o.id=p.order_id
                 left join [laminate] l on l.order_id=o.id
                 left join [slitting] s on s.order_id=o.id
                 left join [bagging] b on b.order_id=o.id
                 where                           
                             1=(case when (o.printing='دارد' and status_p='printed') or o.printing='ندارد' then 1 end)
                         and 1=(case when (o.lamination='دارد' and status_l1='laminated') or o.lamination='ندارد' then 1 end)
                         and 1=(case when (o.lamination='دارد' and l.layer2<>'' and status_l2='laminated2') or o.lamination='ندارد' then 1 end)
                         and 1=(case when (o.coldseal='دارد' and status_c='coldsealed') or o.coldseal='ندارد' then 1 end)
                         and 1=(case when (o.slitting='دارد' and status_s='slitted') or o.slitting='ندارد' then 1 end)
                         and 1=(case when (o.bagging='دارد' and status_b='bagged') or o.bagging='ندارد' then 1 end)
                         and o.id=@id) is not null
        begin
        update [order] set [status]='finished' where id=@id
        end
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See not understood the purpose (bus. rule) of your trigger in first place.

if conndtion with big query is not require.you can bind the same join and condtion in direct update staement,this way multiple orderid can be exceuted and performance will be OK>this query may have bug,that you hv to fix it.But try something like this.

```
UPDATE A SET [STATUS]='FINISHED' FROM [ORDER] A 
INNER JOIN INSERTED C 
ON  A.ID=B.OID
LEFT JOIN [PRINT] P ON O.ID=P.ORDER_ID
LEFT JOIN [LAMINATE] L ON L.ORDER_ID=O.ID
LEFT JOIN [SLITTING] S ON S.ORDER_ID=O.ID
LEFT JOIN [BAGGING] B ON B.ORDER_ID=O.ID
WHERE                           
1=(CASE WHEN (O.PRINTING='دارد' AND STATUS_P='PRINTED') OR O.PRINTING='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
AND 1=(CASE WHEN (O.LAMINATION='دارد' AND STATUS_L1='LAMINATED') OR O.LAMINATION='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
AND 1=(CASE WHEN (O.LAMINATION='دارد' AND L.LAYER2<>'' AND STATUS_L2='LAMINATED2') OR O.LAMINATION='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
AND 1=(CASE WHEN (O.COLDSEAL='دارد' AND STATUS_C='COLDSEALED') OR O.COLDSEAL='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
AND 1=(CASE WHEN (O.SLITTING='دارد' AND STATUS_S='SLITTED') OR O.SLITTING='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
AND 1=(CASE WHEN (O.BAGGING='دارد' AND STATUS_B='BAGGED') OR O.BAGGING='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
```

Comment: you should add `C.STATUS_B ='BAGGED'` in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: `on a.id=c.oid` not `b.oid` ,bagging left join as b 3 line later and `c.status_b='bagged'` in where clause @KumarHarsh

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Take all order id from `inserted` and insert into temp table and do your operations

```
SELECT INSERTED.ORDER_ID AS OID INTO #TEMP1 FROM INSERTED WHERE STATUS_B='bagged';
 IF UPDATE(STATUS_B)
  BEGIN

       IF (SELECT O.ID 
                 FROM [ORDER] O 
                 join #temp1 t
                 on t.OID=o.id
                 LEFT JOIN [PRINT] P ON O.ID=P.ORDER_ID
                 LEFT JOIN [LAMINATE] L ON L.ORDER_ID=O.ID
                 LEFT JOIN [SLITTING] S ON S.ORDER_ID=O.ID
                 LEFT JOIN [BAGGING] B ON B.ORDER_ID=O.ID

                 WHERE                           
                             1=(CASE WHEN (O.PRINTING='دارد' AND STATUS_P='PRINTED') OR O.PRINTING='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
                         AND 1=(CASE WHEN (O.LAMINATION='دارد' AND STATUS_L1='LAMINATED') OR O.LAMINATION='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
                         AND 1=(CASE WHEN (O.LAMINATION='دارد' AND L.LAYER2<>'' AND STATUS_L2='LAMINATED2') OR O.LAMINATION='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
                         AND 1=(CASE WHEN (O.COLDSEAL='دارد' AND STATUS_C='COLDSEALED') OR O.COLDSEAL='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
                         AND 1=(CASE WHEN (O.SLITTING='دارد' AND STATUS_S='SLITTED') OR O.SLITTING='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
                         AND 1=(CASE WHEN (O.BAGGING='دارد' AND STATUS_B='BAGGED') OR O.BAGGING='ندارد' THEN 1 END)
                         ) IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
        UPDATE A SET [STATUS]='FINISHED' FROM [ORDER] A JOIN #TEMP1 C ON  A.ID=B.OID 
        END
     END
```

Comment: this will not work, `(SELECT STATUS_B FROM INSERTED)='BAGGED'` will return more than one row and it will fire an exception

Comment: @MtwStark user has requested for processing all rows at once so i was not checked users entire code. Yes as you said it will throw an exception. User need to handle that with If Exists clause. I will make that change

Comment: @MtwStark Upadted my post.

Comment: I think it is not exact solution, because user need to check `STATUS_B` for each row in inserted and update only that rows.

Comment: whats different between join inserted virtual table and #temp table? i think join inserted table and use where clause is better and smaller @MtwStark

Comment: @F.Kahalaj the right solution is the one of @KumarHarsh. 
The @Buddi solution is logically wrong because it will update ALL the "bagged" rows from INSERTED, if at least one of them matches the WHERE condition. It should instead update only matching rows.
It is also syntactically wrong because the SELECT O.ID could return more than one row and it will throw an exception.
Also there is no need to join `ORDER` table, you should instead use `INSERTED` and `DELETED`